# LEFT Join working in 1 page but not another

Tags: php, mysql, select, left-join

I have this code currently working fine on another page of my site..

```
        $sql = "SELECT topics.topic_id, topics.topic_subject, topics.topic_date, topics.topic_cat, topics.topic_by, users.user_name, users.avatar, categories.cat_id, categories.cat_name
            FROM topics 
            LEFT JOIN users ON topics.topic_by=users.user_id
            LEFT JOIN categories ON categories.cat_id=topics.topic_cat
            WHERE topics.topic_cat = " . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) . " ORDER BY topics.topic_date DESC;";
```

Which puts the **USER AVATAR** on the topic post,  now I am trying to apply to the replys/topic thread and it's not working, here is the code I am using.

```
            $posts_sql = "SELECT
                    posts.post_topic,
                    posts.post_content,
                    posts.post_date,
                    posts.post_by,
                    users.user_id,
                    users.user_name,
                    users.avatar
                FROM
                                        posts
                LEFT JOIN users
                  ON
                    posts.post_by = users.user_id
                   WHERE
                    posts.post_topic = " .  mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong but it's breaking the page.

Comment: query doesn't break pages but output to the pages does...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
...... WHERE posts.post_topic = " .  mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id'])
```

Seems here you're trying to search by topic, but use ID. So nothing is found.

Comment: The page is returning results, just not the "avatar", but it has loaded all the other information fine.

Comment: does mysql returns avatar value from db and it just not displaying? Or db returns null for avatar? Anyway post whole code of fetching and proceeding the db's results

Comment: $posts_sql = "SELECT
      posts.post_topic,
      posts.post_content,
      posts.post_date,
      posts.post_by,
      users.user_id,
      users.user_name,
      users.avatar
     FROM
      posts
     LEFT JOIN users
     ON
      posts.post_by = users.user_id
     WHERE
      posts.post_topic = " . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
      
   $posts_result = mysql_query($posts_sql);
   

<img src="'. $row['avatar'] .'" width="100" height="100">

Comment: Is this whole code? where is mysql_fetch_*() or similar data extraction?

Comment: $posts_sql = "SELECT posts.post_topic, posts.post_content, posts.post_date, posts.post_by, users.user_id, users.user_name, users.avatar
FROM posts 
LEFT JOIN users ON posts.post_by = users.user_id
WHERE posts.post_topic = " . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
   
$posts_result = mysql_query($posts_sql);
if(!$posts_result)
   {
echo '<tr><td>The posts could not be displayed, please try again later.</tr></td></table>';
   }
   else
   {
   
    while($posts_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($posts_result))
    {
     include("includes/new-reply.php");
    }
   }

Comment: new-reply.php is..

<td width="70" rowspan="2" valign="top"><img src="'. $row['avatar'] .'" width="100" height="100"></td>

Comment: you are reading results into $posts_row and try to display $row. Or you have reasinging somewhere?

Comment: Ahh that was it /facepalm, I was using $row instead, thank you.